# Какой код нужен для звука в проекте?

Tags: аудио, java

Здравствуйте. Создал небольшую игру на Java, хочу добавить звук, не знаю какой код надо писать. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вот статья с хабра,там написано как воспроизводить файлы (спасибо некоему [raid](http://habrahabr.ru/users/raid/)) :

[Воспроизведение звука в Java](http://habrahabr.ru/post/191422/)

Перекопирую один фрагментик,чтобы сразу ввести в шок :D (Хотя в этом ничего такого нет)

> Форматы
>
> Пару слов о поддержке форматов
> звуковых файлов: забудьте про mp3 и
> вспомните wav. Также поддерживаются au
> и aif.

Ну и конечно же:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html

Удачи,надеюсь с написание условий для воспроизведения проблем не возникнет)

Comment: вставил в класс игры:

try {
    File soundFile = new File("snd.wav");
    
UnsupportedAudioFileException
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
    
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(ais);
    
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start();

    Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
    clip.stop();
    clip.close();
} catch(IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException exc) {}

ошибок нет, но не знаю куда загружать файл.